# The Add method does not insert a new record into the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

The Add method does not insert a new record into the database.

**Working with the database through the application.**
The **SelectAll** request is executed.
The **Insert** request is not executed. There are no errors.

The **Insert** request code. Not running(Not working)

```
public void Insert(Source source)
{
using (var DbContext = new DbContextSQlite())
{
        dbContext.Sources.Add(source);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

The **selectAll** request code.

```
Public void selectAll() is running
{
using (var DbContext = new DbContextSQlite())
{
        var rows = from x in dbContext.Sources
                   select x;
        int count = rows.Count();
    }
}
```

**Working with the database via DB Browser using SQL queries**
The **Select** query is executed.
The **Insert** request is being executed.

**Used.**

- DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.2;
- Visual Studio Community 2019. 16.11.10;
- Application-Console. .NET Framework 4.7.2;

[Picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeSWx.png)
[Picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7Dd.png)

---

## Update-1

Update-1.
When I try to fully post a question, `stackoverflow.com` gives me comments on the design. I don't understand how to eliminate these comments.
That's why I'm posting the question in an online editor.

**Follow the link -> [Detailed question.](https://hackmd.io/vm_VMg6PQwSI1Yqp-ANUfQ)**

Comment: Maybe some [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) can help.

Comment: @vernou I can't fully post the question yet. stackoverflow has comments on the question.
I am currently dealing with the elimination of stackoverflow comments. As soon as I manage to eliminate the stackoverflow comments, I will try to use your solution.

Comment: @vernou See `Update-1`
Additional information supplemented my question or do I still need to use the link you suggested?

Comment: The code seems good... Do you have try to reproduce in a minimal console application?

Comment: @vernou Yes.
**Questions:**
**1.** Do you think the problem is in the Console Application Framework? Try Winforms or WPF? 
**2.** Then I want to do: The application `Console Framework` <- uses <- `DLL Framework`(The DLL contains `SourceRepository.cs` + DB). 
According to this principle, I want to make a separate DLL for each database. 
**3.** I'm just learning C#.

Comment: 1) I don't think... It's weird. 2) Legit. 3) If you don't need to work with legacy, it would be better to start with .NET Core and Entity Framework Core.